# Java Iterator Remove

Tags: java, iterator

I am new to Java and cannot seem to figure this piece out, any help is appreciated. I am wanting to iterate through my code to find any entry of "3" and remove it. The code I have does not give an error, however when I print it, the entry with "3" is still there.

```
remove("3");

 public static void remove(String studentId){
  Iterator itr = myStudent.iterator();
   for(Student s: myStudent){
   while(itr.hasNext()){
        Object element = itr.next();
        if(element.equals("3")){
            itr.remove();
            }
            }
   System.out.println(s.getstudentId() + " No ID");
```

}
   }

Comment: is myStudent an arraylist? if Yes you can just do myStudent.remove(3)

Comment: myStudent is an arraylist. I want to iterate through the list to find all instances of "3" in the studentId field.